# HTTP request error: name or service not known

Tags: ruby, jruby

I am trying to make HTTP requests via Ruby. When running the following code:

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://google.com/")

# Will print response.body
Net::HTTP.get_print(uri)
```

I get the following error:

```
SocketError: initialize: name or service not known
        from org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyTCPSocket.java:129:in `initialize'
        from org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1179:in `open'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
        from org/jruby/ext/timeout/Timeout.java:105:in `timeout'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:454:in `get_response'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:412:in `get_print'
        from (irb):29:in `evaluate'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1066:in `eval'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1409:in `loop'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1174:in `catch'
        from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1174:in `catch'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/bin/irb:13:in `(root)'
```

This is probably proxy related, but I am not sure. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is your machine connected to internet? Have you tried with another Ruby?

Comment: "This is probably proxy related", so please tell us, are you running through a proxy?

Comment: Yes I am. I tried other ways of doing the same thing using the httpclient library, and in that case it gives me an arg error saying that proxy:8080 is not valid. I tried overriding it with manual proxy settings but it always returns the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby will automatically use the HTTP proxy as specified in your environment variables.

```
EXPORT http_proxy=http://foo.bar:8080/
ruby your_http_script.rb
```

Comment: I might not be able to override the HTTP_PROXY directly. Also, I can't override it in the constructor (is this a bug?).
client = HTTPClient.new(:proxy => 'http://myproxy:8080')
ArgumentError: unsupported proxy proxy:8080

Comment: I've fonund a work-around: since ruby stores all environment variables in the hash-table ENV, I just overwrote it in there, and reran the httpclient code. No more problems.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me. No proxy was in use.

The reason was that I was not running as root and `/etc/resolv.conf` didn't have read permissions to anyone other than root. Adding read permissions solved the host resolving problem.